# How to create a serializable class to deserialize an XML with a single node?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I can't find a way to create a serializable class in C# to handle deserialization from an XML that has a single node, like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<code>
    GM47R4 5I3RR4 LUB
</code>
```

I've been trying using XSD.exe to first create the XSD and then the C# class but it didn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Code));
    var code = new Code {Value = "xx"};
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var wri = new StringWriter(sb);
    xmlSer.Serialize(wri, code);
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Code")]
    public class Code
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Code xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
xx
</Code>
```

And can thus be used to deserialize your xml as well, namespaces will be ignored by default.

Answer (score 1):

@woutervs' code is good if you really need a custom class. For XML this simple, is it really necessary to create a separate class? Probably not, unless you have requirements you didn't include in your question.

I'd just use the `XDocument` class:

```
const string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<code>
    GM47R4 5I3RR4 LUB
</code>";
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

Console.WriteLine(document.Element("code").Value.Trim());
```

`XDocument` can easily be used to create XML, too:

```
var document = new XDocument(new XElement("code", "GM47R4 5I3RR4 LUB"));

Console.WriteLine(document);
```